# Drupaliest way to remove login and registration page descriptions

Tags: 6, users

How to remove the descriptions from log in and registration page ?

[image: Because]

I need to remove the description from the fields which are listed in the images.

These are both log in and registration page.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you write a hook for user login form alter, then you can set the #description to null. you need something like this:

```
function YOURMODULE_user_login_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
    $form['name']['#description'] = '';
}
```

Comment: Is there any common way to remove all the descriptions globally instead of mentioning in singular.

Comment: if you want to do it globally then consider doing it with css (display: none), otherwise i dont think you can do it with any hook.

Comment: I have never tested it, but in theory, you should be able to expand on the code example above, to work on _all_ forms, and then overwrite the description. Whether or not that's a good idea, is a completely different matter.

Comment: +1 for 'Whether or not that's a good idea, is a completely different matter.'

Comment: You could also try using [Tipsy](http://drupal.org/project/tipsy) which will hide all descriptions and then display them on mouseover.  Seems like a much better idea than hiding them completely.